# Have you used Google's Directory API?

Tags: c#, directory, google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to use Google Directory API Library for .NET to maintain email addresses for a domain. The latest library is google-admin-directory_v1-rev6-csharp-1.4.0-beta. The best and farthest I've gotten so far is to receive a 403 error (Not Authorized to access this resource/api).

Has anyone out there successfully used it? If so, could you share some code, tips, or tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used it and got some success in creating a console-application.
At the moment I'm trying to find a way to skip the copy/paste of the authorization code.
Don't forget to turn on API access in your APIs Console.
I'll show you a small sample:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Samples.Helper;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Admin.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Admin.directory_v1.Data;



namespace Bergstedts.CreateNewUser
{
    public class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         // Display the header and initialize the sample.
        CommandLine.EnableExceptionHandling();
        Console.WriteLine("Create users in a google apps domain!");
        Console.WriteLine("by Jonas Bergstedt 2013");

        // Get the user data and store in user object
        Console.Write("Email: ");
        string userId = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Givenname: ");
        string GivenName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Familyname: ");
        string FamilyName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string Password = Console.ReadLine();

        User newuserbody = new User();
        UserName newusername = new UserName();
        newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = userId;
        newusername.GivenName = GivenName;
        newusername.FamilyName = FamilyName;
        newuserbody.Name = newusername;
        newuserbody.Password = Password;

        // Register the authenticator.
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
            {
                ClientIdentifier = "<your clientId from Google APIs Console>",
                ClientSecret = "<your clientsecret from Google APIs Console>",
            };

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                Authenticator = auth,
                ApplicationName = "Create User",
                ApiKey = "<your API Key from Google APIs console> (not sure if needed)"             
            });

        User results = service.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("User :" + results.PrimaryEmail + " is created");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
    {
        // Get the auth URL:
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryUser.GetStringValue() });
        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

        // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
        Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Authorization Code: ");
        string authCode = Console.ReadLine();

        // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
       return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hello. Did you use NuGet package ? or how do you download Directory API? Thanks in advance.

Comment: JoBe Can I e-mail you for a problem about a peace of code?

Comment: @OrlandoHerrera StackOverflow makes it intentionally difficult to contact other members, because it's not a social site. As such requests for private help are frowned upon unless person you are asking indicated he is willing to help privately *before you asked*. But even in this case this is not the best idea, as we are meant to help each other here on the site. Post your question. Let other people see and answer it. Let yet more others learn from your question and their answers. That's the StackOverflow way! =)