# Google apps Directory API (1.6 and above) DotNetOpenAuth not resolving

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

This code is changing fast and hard to get a handle on what works and what doesn't...

I was looking at this post: [Have you used Google's Directory API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453391/have-you-used-googles-directory-api)

Which is using the 1.4 library.

I installed the 1.6 API through nuget. However, the NativeApplicationClient and IAuthorizationState cannot be resolved. I was under the impression that I no longer needed the DotNetOpenAuth nuget package or the Google.Apis.Authentication package (which is where I believe they are resolved.

This is the complete and modified code I am playing with: (if you have a better example of creating users using the new API I'd like to see that!)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Diagnostics;

using Google;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth;
using Google.Apis.Download;
using Google.Apis.Logging;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload; 
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data;


namespace GoogleAddUser
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Display the header and initialize the sample.
        //CommandLine.EnableExceptionHandling();
        Console.WriteLine("Create users in a google apps domain!");
        Console.WriteLine("by Jonas Bergstedt 2013");

        // Get the user data and store in user object
        Console.Write("Email: ");
        string userId = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Givenname: ");
        string GivenName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Familyname: ");
        string FamilyName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string Password = Console.ReadLine();

        User newuserbody = new User();
        UserName newusername = new UserName();
        newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = userId;
        newusername.GivenName = GivenName;
        newusername.FamilyName = FamilyName;
        newuserbody.Name = newusername;
        newuserbody.Password = Password;

        // Register the authenticator.
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
        {
            ClientIdentifier = "<your clientId from Google APIs Console>",
            ClientSecret = "<your clientsecret from Google APIs Console>",
        };

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            Authenticator = auth,
            ApplicationName = "Create User",
            ApiKey = "<your API Key from Google APIs console> (not sure if needed)"
        });

        User results = service.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("User :" + results.PrimaryEmail + " is created");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
    {
        // Get the auth URL:
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryUser.GetStringValue() });
        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

        // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
        Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Authorization Code: ");
        string authCode = Console.ReadLine();

        // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
        return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From release 1.6.0-beta we presented a new Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package (Google.Apis.Authentication which uses DNOA is obsolete!). You already installed that package, because all the new APIs have a reference to it. Take a look in our [OAuth2](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2) wiki page for more details about how to use the new OAuth2 flows (it's not magic anymore, now the flows actually make sense!)

I recommend you subscribing to our [announcement blog](http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/) and optionally to my [personal blog](http://peleyal.blogspot.com/) to get more information about the client library. In our announcement blog we described the reason the new OAuth2 pacakge.

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: I don't see a subscription link anywhere on the blog, is there somewhere else I need to go to subscribe to it?

Comment: You can use http://feedly.com/ for example to manage your subscriptions to blogs (That's what I'm doing). You can also join our external group (https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/google-api-dotnet-client). Information on a new release is published in the external group as well.